# Flask Project root directory on openshift

Tags: python, flask, openshift

I'm getting started with flask and I'm deploying my app to openshift.

My apps code:

```
def get_users():
    f = open('./users.txt')
    ....
```

when I run:

```
$ rhc tail flaskpq
```

I see:

> [Sun Jun 21 09:05:20 2015] [error] [client 127.2.78.1]     f =
>   open('./user.txt') [Sun Jun 21 09:05:20 2015] [error] [client
>   127.2.78.1] IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './users.txt'

My suspicion is that my relative reference to users.txt in my projects root directory is no longer valid on deployment to openshift. It works fine locally on win7. What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this to get the directory for the app:

```
user_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./users.txt"))
```

It's what I do on heroku. Don't forget ____file___ will be the directory the file resides in.  This might or might not be your application root folder.

Answer (score 1):

You should generally not write paths in pure strings. This is dangerous when working cross-platform. Please use the functions in `os` and `os.path`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that on openshift you can create/write files only under the `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` so I personally use following kind of approach.

```
DATA_DIR = os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR', ".")
def get_users():
    f = open(os.path.join(DATA_DIR,'users.txt')
```

And I copy the file using `rhc scp` to correct place if needed.